# Windows 10 mobile sideloading certificate

Tags: uwp, certificate, windows-10-mobile, code-signing-certificate, sideloading

**Situation:** I am developing an application for a company. They sideload the Windows 10 mobile app. Now the certificate has expired and I have created my own certificate with `makecert.exe`. The test certificate from Visual Studio only is valid for one year, which is too less.

The smartphone is unlocked for sideloading. I have copied the certificate and the .appx file on the smartphone. Unfortunately I can't install the app.

The app is of course signed with my own created certificate and I double checked that. Then I installed the certificate, which was "successfully". Of course Windows 10 mobile never shows an error here. 
When I want to install the app, nothing happens.

When switching the phone to developer mode, it works. So in my opinion the only reason why it could fail in the sideloading mode is the certificate. Creation of the certificate and code signing do not throw any errors.

Any suggenstions?

Thanks in regards!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't sideload apps without Developer Mode activated, no matter what certificate is in use!

Comment: Actually there are the options to enable sideloading and to enable developer mode

Comment: I think you can buy code signing certificates that are valid for more than 1 year.

Comment: Or have the organization/client signup for a Windows Enterprise store. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/business-store and bypass all the sideloading complexity.